# Smith Normal Form of a Cayley Graph of the Symmetric Group

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics, smith-normal-form

Let $A_n$ be the adjacency matrix of the Cayley graph $\text{Cay}(S_n,C_n)$ where $C_n \subseteq S_n$ is the conjugacy class of $n$-cycles of the symmetric group $S_n$. Since the generating set of this Cayley graph is a conjugacy class, it is not too difficult to use the representation theory of $S_n$ to elegantly count the number of nonzero eigenvalues of $A$:

$$ \text{rank}(A_n) = \binom{n-1}{0}^2 + \binom{n-1}{1}^2 + \cdots + \binom{n-1}{n-1}^2 = \binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}.$$

I am interested in the rank of $A_n$ modulo $p$ where $p$ is an odd prime for all $n$. One way to determine this would be to compute the Smith Normal Form of $A_n$ (over $\mathbb{Z}$). Let $D_n = \text{diag}(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_r,0,\cdots,0)$ such that $s_i | s_{i+1}$ for all $1 \leq i < r := \text{rank}(A)$ be the Smith Normal Form of $A_n$. Computations for small $n$ show that the nonzero $s_i$'s are all powers of 2, which might suggest that $\text{rank}_p(A_n) = \text{rank}(A_n)$ for all $n$ and odd primes $p$.

It seems unlikely that one can divine unimodular matrices $U_n,V_n$ such that $D_n = U_nA_nV_n$ for all $n$, so I would like to think of $A_n$ as an endomorphism of the group algebra $\mathbb{F}_p[S_n]$ and perhaps use $p$-modular representation theory of $S_n$ to say something about the image of $A_n$. (Here, we are assuming $p$ is small, i.e., $p \mid n!$, so $\mathbb{F}_p[S_n]$ is not semisimple.)

Generally speaking, working with modular representations of $S_n$ is also difficult; however, the image of $A_n$ (in the characteristic 0 case) is the direct sum of the *hook-shaped* Specht modules, which are pretty well-understood, even in the modular case. In particular, Peel (1971) showed for odd primes $p$ that the hook-shaped Specht modules $S^{(n-k,1^k)}_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ are simple when $p \not \mid n$ and determined their composition series when $p \mid n$.

Experimentally, if one picks $b \in S^{(n-k,1^k)}_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ to be a $(n-k,1^k)$-*standard polytabloid* (which is a $\{0,\pm1 \}$-valued vector well-defined for any Specht module over any field), then $A_nx = b$ indeed has a solution over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for small $k$, odd primes $p$, and $n$. In the case that $p \not \mid n$, because $A_nx = b$ has a solution, it follows that $A_nx = b'$ for any $b' \in S^{(n-k,1^k)}_{\mathbb{F}_p}$, as $S^{(n-k,1^k)}_{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is irreducible by Peel's result. Here, we are "using the modular representation theory of $S_n$", but the problem is that showing a solution $x$ for $A_nx = b$ exists over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for all $0 \leq k < n$ and odd primes $p$ seems to involve similar row-operation-type calculations as putting $A_n$ into Smith Normal Form.

My (open-ended) question is whether there is a more clever way to leverage such information about the modular representation theory of $S_n$ that would circumvent row and column operations to say something about the Smith Normal Form of $A_n$ or $\text{rank}_p(A)$ for odd primes $p$.

**EDIT** Here's the SNF for small $n$ (thanks Dima for verifying these):

$n = 2$ the SNF is $1^2$

$n = 3$ the SNF is $1^42^2$

$n = 4$ the SNF is $1^{8}2^{12}$

$n = 5$ the SNF is $1^{16}2^{52}8^2$

$n = 6$ the SNF is $1^{32}2^{200}8^{20}$

$n = 7$ the SNF is $1^{64}2^{728}4^{2}8^{128}16^2$

(I have not gone beyond $n=7$, as this would take some time.)

Comment: Does it suffice to show that the lowest (in the sense of degree) nonzero coefficient of the minimal polynomial of $A_n $ (or of some polynomial over $\mathbb Z $ that vanishes on $A_n $) is a power of $2$ ? My intuition suggests that this should somehow force the nonzero invariant factors to be powers of $2$ as well.

Comment: @darijgrinberg by analogy with "sandpile groups" this looks plausable. There the order of the corresponding abelian group is computed by determinant of a maximal nonzero minor, which is indeed the coefficient of the lowest degree monomial in the char. poly.

Comment: Okay, let me be more precise. Let $A $ be a symmetric integer matrix (such as your $A_n $) and $p $ be an integer polynomial such that $p\left (A\right) = 0$ and such that the lowest (in the sense of degree) nonzero coefficient of $p $ is a power of $2$. Then, over $\mathbb Z \left [1/2\right] $, the homomorphism represented by $A $ decomposes as a direct sum of an invertible homomorphism with a zero map. That is, it has a Smith normal form over $\mathbb Z \left [1/2\right] $ in which the diagonal entries are $0$s and $1$s. Thus, its rank does not change when modding out an odd prime.

Comment: Now of course we need to find such a $p $. But the eigenvalues of $A_n $ are known, so this should not be hard. You just need to prove that the product of all nonzero eigenvalues is a power of $2$.

Comment: I checked the case n=5 and there the minimal polynomial of A is $x_1^4-22x_1^3-72x_1^2+576x_1$, so you get 3 as a divisor, as well.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - this is basically a part of the approach I talk about in my answer below - so such a straightforward argument doesn't fly. One needs a more subtle approach.

Comment: Ah, thats a pity. Is there anything useful in arXiv:1612.08124?

Comment: the minimal polynomial of $A_n$ (or perhaps an "almost" minimal in some cases) is the characteristic polynomial of the "collapse" of $A_n$ by certain subgroup of the automorphism group; one can also think of the collapsed matrix as the image under of $A_n$ in the regular representation $\rho$ of the algebra of conj. class sum matrices. Perhaps one can use something better than $\rho$.

By the way, one can look at SNF of this collapsed matrix $\rho(A_n)$ - and well, apart from powers of 2 one also sees there terms of the form $k!$, for $k\leq n$.

Comment: Probably this discrepancy between the divisors of the lowest nonzero coefficient of the minimal polynomial and SNF is due to $A$ ceasing to be normal of the alg. closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. E.g. for $n=5$ and $p=3$ the rank of $(A\mod p)^2$ drops to 36 (and stays so for the higher powers).

Answer (score 1):

I would think of $A_n$ as an element of the commutative algebra spanned by the  conjugacy class sums of $S_n$. It is known that the multiplication coefficients of such an algebra are determined by the character table of the underlying group, see e.g. the documentation on the GAP system function [ClassMultiplicationCoefficient](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap71.html#X7E2EA9FE7D3062D3).

An advantage of working in this algebra is that its dimension equals the number of conjugacy classes rather than the order of the group (i.e. the multiplicies of eigenvalues of $A_n$ will be taken care of once you pass to the image of $A_n$ in this algebra via the natural algebra isomorphism).
You'd need to keep track of the eigenvalue multiplicites, but this is all well-understood, e.g. in terms of the underlying [*association scheme*](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cgodsil/assocs/pdfs/Assoc.pdf) (an object in algberaic combinatorics that generalises this sort of setting).

---

This does not seem to give one a direct (or any?) way to compute the SNF of $A_n$, but as you are interested in the $p$-rank of $A_n$ rather than its SNF, this looks reasonable.

Comment: I am well-aware that one can view $A_n$ as the $(n)$-associate of the conjugacy-class association scheme of $S_n$, but I do not see why this allows one to say anything about the $p$-rank for all odd primes $p$. Naively, one could look at the eigenvalues of $A_n$ modulo $p$ to get some sort of estimate; however, they are highly composite (for small $p$ they are 0 mod $p$).

Comment: you might know that old paper for the case of strongly regular graphs: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1022438616684.pdf
It suggests that eigenvalues might help...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this paper. I had skimmed it quite some time ago, but I'll give it a more thorough read.

Comment: Can you post more details of your computation, i.e., the actual SNF for small values of $n$?

Comment: I computed using GAP that for n=6 one gets rank 252, and SNF being $1^{32}2^{200}8^{20}$

Comment: for n=5 rank is 70, and SNF is $1^{16}2^{52}8^2$.

Comment: for n=2 rank is 2 and SNF is $1^2$; 
for n=3 rank is 6 and SNF is $1^4 2^2$; 
for n=4 rank is 20 and SNF is $1^8 2^{12}$.

Comment: Thanks for providing the SNF for small $n$ Dima: those calculations match mine. I'll edit the question once I compute the n=7 case.

Comment: for n=7 rank is 924 an SNF is $1^{64}2^{728}4^2 8^{128} 16^2$.  (well, it's tempting to say that 1 occurs $2^{n+1}$ times :-)) I guess computing n=8 might take a while.

Comment: you beat me to it! and yes I believe there is a proof of that statement: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1506 (in this paper, the 2-rank of a related matrix is computed, and the same techniques carry over to $A_n$ I believe).

Comment: I'm using GAP since 1993, you know, give me a credit :-)

Comment: @NathanLindzey Did it work out?